# Can i afford to add win forms resource files in class library project

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I had a fairly big project and has lot of logic in form of classes in a folder.

Now i need to make a separate project that contains those classes.

All those classes are referring resource files for language..

Like

```
Localization.MyStringVariable
```

Copying the resource files too in a separate project make it build but throws error at runtime.

**The error is resource files no loaded for neutral culture...**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Exact Error:

{"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Project.Localization.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"ProjectDAL\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}

Comment: We have loads of class libraries that have localisable resources - it works just fine.

Comment: @MatthewWatson No it is not working. IN the class library i am calling resource files and not in forms through class library